# Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

Tensorflow is only using the CPU and wont use the GPU. I assume its because it expects Cuda 10.0 and it finds 10.2.

I had installed 10.2 but have purged it and installed 10.0.

Im running Ubuntu 19.10, AMD Ryzen 2700 Cpu, RTX 2080 S.
I have installed the 440 Nvidia driver, It says cuda version 10.2 when i check with nvidia-smi and nvcc -version.

```
From pip3: tensorflow-gpu           1.14.0
           tensorflow-datasets       2.0.0               
           tensorflow-estimator     1.14.0                           
           tensorflow-metadata      0.21.1
```

From Nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.44       Driver Version: 440.44       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:08:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   48C    P8    13W / 250W |    369MiB /  7979MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1110      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            18MiB |
|    0      1611      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            73MiB |
|    0      1816      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         108MiB |
|    0      2655      C   python3                                      115MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

from nvcc --version

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:24:38_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

But when i check the version.txt i get 10.0.130

```
cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt 
CUDA Version 10.0.130
```

I check the devices with :

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

result:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 4810338588393992961
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 7271419476897292826
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 4332706623198547606
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
```

How do i register the 10.0.130
Is that the reason why it wont run on GPU? Its super slow on the 8 Core CPU. Any advice?

Here is the log:

```
2020-02-13 14:11:31.411277: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-02-13 14:11:31.440150: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3193485000 Hz
2020-02-13 14:11:31.441076: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5625b689c790 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2020-02-13 14:11:31.441123: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2020-02-13 14:11:31.443001: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-02-13 14:11:31.472935: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-13 14:11:31.473407: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.845
pciBusID: 0000:08:00.0
2020-02-13 14:11:31.474361: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:31.487124: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:31.496148: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:31.498873: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:31.514842: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:31.525992: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:31.526168: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64
2020-02-13 14:11:31.526183: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1663] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices...
2020-02-13 14:11:31.618627: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-02-13 14:11:31.618655: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
2020-02-13 14:11:31.618662: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
2020-02-13 14:11:31.620367: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero

2020-02-13 14:11:31.621395: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5625b732d5f0 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2020-02-13 14:11:31.621407: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER, Compute Capability 7.5
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 13330791690361361129
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 11872341970779952422
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 15007819717683015571
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
WARNING:tensorflow:From pokeGAN.py:172: The name tf.variable_scope is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.variable_scope instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From pokeGAN.py:174: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From pokeGAN.py:77: The name tf.get_variable is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_variable instead.


2020-02-13 14:11:33.799163: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-13 14:11:33.799597: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.845
pciBusID: 0000:08:00.0
2020-02-13 14:11:33.799646: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:33.799658: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:33.799669: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:33.799684: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:33.799695: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:33.799706: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:33.799777: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64
2020-02-13 14:11:33.799786: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1663] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices...
2020-02-13 14:11:33.800016: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-02-13 14:11:33.800028: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      
WARNING:tensorflow:From pokeGAN.py:203: The name tf.train.Saver is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.Saver instead.

2020-02-13 14:11:34.197990: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/node/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py:1276: checkpoint_exists (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
WARNING:tensorflow:From pokeGAN.py:211: start_queue_runners (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
To construct input pipelines, use the `tf.data` module.
total training sample num:91
batch size: 64, batch num per epoch: 1, epoch num: 5000
start training...
```

Comment: did you found the solution?

Answer (score 11):

Before you do anything more drastic, maybe you just need to set environment variables `CUDNN_PATH` and/or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Check with:

```
echo $CUDNN_PATH       # should exist and give a good path
ls $CUDNN_PATH         # should contain stuff like a lib subdir with libcudnn .so files
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH  # should exist and contain CUDNN_PATH
```

If you need changes, I set them with:

```
export CUDNN_PATH=$(dirname $(python -c "import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.__file__)"))
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDNN_PATH}/lib
```

But there are other ways, like @User_Rebo's:

```
export CUDNN_PATH="$HOME/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nvidia/cudnn"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CUDNN_PATH/lib":"/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
```

Some people set these in their .bashrc; that's an easy way to not forget, but I personally prefer to set them in each session I want to use them.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from your logs it looks like tensorflow finds the correct cuda version but the **cudnn** library is missing.

```
2020-02-13 14:11:31.474361: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-02-13 14:11:31.526168: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64
```

Have you installed the correct version of cudnn? As you can see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)
tensorflow 1.14 also requires cudnn 7.4

Answer (score 3):

#### Install Nvidia Toolkit (Linux / WSL):

Select `runfile (local)` from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive

It's recommended to install the supported version stated here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#software_requirements
Also tested with CUDA `12.3.0`.

```bash
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.8.0/local_installers/cuda_11.8.0_520.61.05_linux.run
sudo sh cuda_11.8.0_520.61.05_linux.run
```

If you get this message: `Existing package manager installation of the driver found.`
Run the installer with these options: `--toolkit --silent --override`

Check CUDA version:

```bash
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --version
```

#### Install Tensorflow

```bash
pip uninstall tensorflow # Uninstall previous one to not confuse with the installation without CUDA support.
pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]
```

Check Tensorflow version:

```bash
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
```

Verify CUDA support, by getting the number of available GPU's (1 or more):

```bash
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))"
```

---

With Tensorflow **minor 2.15.0**, don't forget to add your environment variables:

> e.g. `nano $HOME/.bashrc`
>
> ```bash
> # Need to adapt to your python version:
> export CUDNN_PATH="$HOME/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nvidia/cudnn"
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CUDNN_PATH/lib":"/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
> # ...
> export PATH="$PATH":"/usr/local/cuda/bin"
> ```
>
> Given that `/usr/local/cuda` points to your actual cuda installation like `/usr/local/cuda-11.8`.

---

#### Uninstall CUDA

```bash
sudo /usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin/cuda-uninstaller
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me to solve this issue was to completely remove CUDA and reinstall it again.